# Resolve-DnsName -Server on specific Port

Tags: powershell, networking, dns

I'm trying to run a nslookup by specifying the host IP as as follows:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Type A -TcpOnly -DnsOnly -NoHostsFile -QuickTimeout -Server $THIS_MACHINES_IP -Name $NAME_OF_SERVER
```

I get the following error when it runs:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The problem is that `$THIS_MACHINES_IP` server is running in a restricted environment so only few ports are open. In this case I need to run it on port `7450`, i.e. `$THIS_MACHINES_IP:7450`.

Does anyone know how I can provide the port number when using `Resolve-DnsName` or alternative means to achieve the same?

Answer (score 6):

`Resolve-DnsName` doesn't allow changing the port. You could use `nslookup`, though:

```
nslookup -port=7450 $NAME_OF_SERVER $THIS_MACHINES_IP
```

However, running a nameserver on any port other than 53 is not a good idea in the first place. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I guess it's more like a "test it locally in a container" kind of scenario, yet again a valid one.

Comment: > running a nameserver on any port other than 53 is not a good idea

That's completely incorrect.  It's a bad idea if you have a Windows environment and need to set a Forwarder in your Windows DNS Server.  It appears Microsoft just can't handle that.  In every other environment is works well and may be required as part of a good DNS strategy (i.e. using something like dnsdist)